# I'd like to set a breakpoint on ng-template

Tags: angular

I have this line in my html.

```
<ng-template ngFor let-i="index" let-c="count" let-contact [ngForOf]="contacts">
```

The ngFor seems to be executing when I don't expect it to.  I'd like to "set a breakpoint" to see whether it is actually recreating the elements.

What comes to mind is to do something like this:

```
<ng-template ngFor let-i="index" let-c="count" let-contact let-dummy="functionCalledOnEachIteration" [ngForOf]="contacts">
```

And then set a breakpoint in functionCalledOnEachIteration.  But that syntax is not accepted.

Is there a way to do what I have in mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### ngFor

Yes, there is such syntax:

```
<ng-template
    ngFor let-contact [ngForOf]="contacts"
    let-i="index" let-c="count" [ngForTrackBy]="functionCalledOnEachIteration"

>
```

in component:

```
public functionCalledOnEachIteration(index, item) {
  debugger;
  console.log('trackByFn', index, item);
  return item;
}
```

trackBy is normally used for loop optimalization (see: https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)

### ng-template debugging

For ng-template debugging, I usually use also this trick:

Imagine you don't know which let-x='???' are valid for template. You can try:

```
<ng-template let-context="valueOf()">{{log(context)}}</ng-template>
```

and

```
public log(x) { console.log('template log:', x); }
```

valueOf is part of object.prototype, and if it is not overridden, then it returns itself. When you have template-context object instance, you can see all its properties. These are the ones you can access via let-x='???' syntax.

Comment: Mino, you are the awesomest !   I am going to go apply this information right now.